# My ISP backbone is unstable. How can I route my traffic around this?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I am situated in China and I am experiencing really unstable speed to my VPN. This is the results of `mtr`

[image]

I see that the problematic nodes are `59.43.130.122`, `59.43.181.186` and `203.100.48.62`. After digging around using http://whatismyipaddress.com/ I see that all of these nodes belongs to my ISP's backbone.

Is there anything I can do right now to route my traffic differently?

Comment: No. You have no control over a network controlled by someone else.

Comment: well, generally you can't control the routing of a path beyond where you enter it. Each node decides how it will send to the next hop of the path, and you can't really influence that, especially since its the path your VPN connection passes through.

Comment: The thing you can do to route your traffic right now is to tell your ISP that they have a problem and that you have evidence that needs to get to their network engineers. Your ISP is the only one that can help you here.

Comment: Hey everyone, unfortunately, these network issues are related to the recent tightening in censorships in China. I firmly believe these are put in place to thwart attempts to get around the GFW.

Comment: In the past you could use [source routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_routing), but most routers won't support that today, sorry.

Comment: The MTR does not tell you anything meaningful about stability. All it says is that ICMP is fairly stably prioritised and some routers are designed to drop packets destined for them rather then packets routed through them.

Comment: @barrycarter is not right about source routing - it would not help,  and this functionality is getting slightly easier to access - but it's still tricky on cheap routers (*wrt brings routing options to more low end routers then in the past)